# Mixed lexicographic and numeric sorting

Tags: sorting, command-line, text-processing, unix

I have a list such as:

### input.txt

```
foo.bar.1
foo.bar.2
foo.bar.3.x.y.z
foo.bar.10
foo.bar.0
baz.10.qux
baz.3.qux
```

that needed to be sorted. I need to treat this as a dot separated
fields, where numeric fields are needed to be sorted numerically.

So I wrote:

### mixsort.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
seq = map(lambda l: map(lambda s: (s.isdigit() and [int(s)] or [s])[0], l),
          [ s.rstrip().split('.') for s in sys.stdin.readlines() ])
seq.sort()
sys.stdout.write( '\n'.join(['.'.join([str(i) for i in l]) for l in seq]) )
```

### usage

```
$ mixsort.py < input.txt
baz.3.qux
baz.10.qux
foo.bar.0
foo.bar.1
foo.bar.2
foo.bar.3.x.y.z
foo.bar.10
```

But am I re-inventing the wheel here? Is there a common
*nix utility that do what I need? is there a switch to `sort(1)` that
will help me out. (note that the position of the numeric fields is
unknown). Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### coreutils version 8.7

Use version sort: `sort -V`:

Input:

```
frayser@gentoo ~ $ cat /tmp/list.ran
foo.bar.1
foo.bar.2
baz.10.qux
baz.3.qux
foo.bar.0
foo.bar.3.x.y.z
foo.bar.10
```

Sort:

```
frayser@gentoo ~ $ LC_ALL=C sort -V /tmp/list.ran
baz.3.qux
baz.10.qux
foo.bar.0
foo.bar.1
foo.bar.2
foo.bar.3.x.y.z
foo.bar.10
```

I found this in the [info pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort) as suggested in the manpage: `info coreutils "sort invocation"`

Comment: Grate suggestion. Using `sort -V` or `sort --version-sort` is a clever trick that utilize the dot separation in both my question and in version numbers. It is the correct answer for this question. Unfortunately the version of `sort(1)` available for me does not support this option.